# EmailTemplate DeveloperName field is not accessible for community user in managed package

Tags: apex, email, email-template

I wanted to send an email using one of my Email Templates in Salesforce depending on the action of my community user. The email template folder where this email template is stored has Read/Write access & is accessible to all users.

I have the following check for DeveloperName field of EmailTemplate object in one of my Apex class to ensure template is accessible for the community user. However, the condition check always return field to be inaccessible to my community users and therefore no email is sent. This behaviour only happens on our managed package orgs. Unmanaged package orgs / scratch orgs send the emails with no issues.

Anybody able to help as to what else I'm missing here?

```
if (!Schema.sObjectType.EmailTemplate.fields.DeveloperName.isAccessible()) {
        throw new MyException(System.Label.NoAccessToEmailTemplate);
    } else {
        emailTemplateId = new EmailTemplateSelector().getEmailTemplateId(template);

    } 
    // send email logic here...
```

Comment: did you have any solution for this?